# Plotting a chart from nested JSON list

Tags: python, json, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the price data I took from the CoinGecko API. To get the data itself, I used this command:
`mbrp = coingecko.get_coin_market_chart_range_by_id("bitcoin","usd","1577836800","1609459200")["prices"]`
The output of that command looks like this:
`[[1577836800000, 7195.153895430029],[1577923200000, 7193.7546679601],...,[1609459200000, 29022.41839530417]]`
Where the first column (1577836800000) is the UNIX date of the data and the second column is the price (7195.153895430029). I didn't know what to do to make this data plottable, so I tried to plot the data directly like this: 
`mbrpdf = pandas.DataFrame(mbrp)`
`mbrpdf.plot()`
As I expected this approach did not work. I suspect this is because I haven't removed the outer brackets of the output and the UNIX time column. My question is, how do I remove the outer brackets and the first column?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pd.Series's index can be the x axis, and it's values show as y axis .

```
alist = [[1577836800000, 7195.153895430029],[1577923200000, 7193.7546679601],[1609459200000, 29022.41839530417]]
df = pd.DataFrame(alist, columns=['ts', 'price'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'], unit='ms')
obj = df.set_index('date')['price']
obj.plot()
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you